# the returned form request is object, how do i convert accept it and turn into array

Tags: laravel, reactjs

```
public function updateWorksByStudentId(Request $requests, $id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id)->user_works;

        $works = $requests['sample_work']; //uncomment when sending request
        //$works = ['getmi', 'test', 'awts']; //for testing

        foreach($student as $id => $student_work)
        {
            $work = UserWork::find($student_work->id);
            $work->update(['sample_work' => $works[$id]]);
            $sample_work[]= $work;
        }

        return response()->json($sample_work, 200);
    }
```

The form request returned [Object, Object, ...] How do I receive it from my controller and turn it into array.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$model->get()` to get data in array. I have not tested it, but give it a try. Let me know if it works for you.

```
public function updateWorksByStudentId(Request $requests, $id) {
    $student = Student::find($id) - > user_works;

    $works = $requests['sample_work']; //uncomment when sending request
    //$works = ['getmi', 'test', 'awts']; //for testing

    foreach($student as $id => $student_work) {
        $work = UserWork::find($student_work - > id);
        $work->update(['sample_work' => $works[$id]]);
        // Old
        // $sample_work[] = $work;
        // New
        $sample_work[] = $work->get();
    }

    return response()->json($sample_work, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create $sample_work array before foreach :
Try this :

```
public function updateWorksByStudentId(Request $requests, $id)
{
    $student = Student::find($id)->user_works;

    $works = $requests['sample_work']; //uncomment when sending request
    //$works = ['getmi', 'test', 'awts']; //for testing
    $sample_work = array();
    foreach($student as $id => $student_work)
    {
        $work = UserWork::find($student_work->id);
        $work->update(['sample_work' => $works[$id]]);
        $sample_work[]= $work;
    }

    return response()->json($sample_work, 200);
}
```